# ERROR ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined in SSR angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, server-side-rendering

I am working on SSR in Angular version 11. When I call cdn json file that time getting run time error `ERROR ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined` and not showing data on SSR.

Please help what can I do

***abc.component.ts***

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, EventEmitter, Inject, Input, LOCALE_ID, OnInit, Output, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
cardInfo: any;

 constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    @Inject(LOCALE_ID) public languageId: string,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId,
  ) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getJsonData().subscribe((res) => {
      this.cardInfo = res;
    });
  }
  getJsonData() {
    return this.http.get(
      `https://cdn.researcher.life/rlife/json/advisory-board-members/advisory-board-members-${this.languageId}-v4.json`,
    );
  }
```

Comment: When do you expect this http call to happen? During the server side rendering?

Comment: When my page renders on the server-side.